# Anaconda plugin not working on Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublime-anaconda

I am using a Sublime Text 3 portable app and I simply dragged all of the Anaconda files into the `packages` directory, i.e. `\Sublime Text Build 3114 x64\Data\Packages\anaconda-1.3.4`.

However, I keep getting an error in the console that says `ImportError: No module named 'anaconda-1'`. I can see the Anaconda option when I right-click anywhere, but all of the commands in the Anaconda menu are greyed out. Nothing else, like the auto-complete, is working either.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Fixed by using `PackageControl` to reinstall `Anaconda`.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using PackageControl to reinstall Anaconda.